# Backbone.model.save(): POST(create) / PUT(update) logic doesn't match application logic - how to avoid PUT in certain situations?

Tags: javascript, rest, http, backbone.js, pyramid

I'm creating an Web-Application (Frontend and Backend, so both are under my control) using Backbone and Pyramid, being connected via a RESTful API.

During development I encountered a problem several times by now, where Backbone PUTs (=updates) a new model, while it actually should POST (=create) it.

Backbone decides whether to POST or UPDATE a model depending of the presence of an `ID`-field (if no `ID` present in the current model: -> POST/create | if so: PUT/update).

However I encountered several situations by now, where this behaviour doesn't match my application logic.

Let's say our main model (and its objects being persistently saved in a relational database in the backend) is called `Foo`, having fields like `id`, `field_1`, `field_2`.

**Example #1**: Creating a template or preview of `Foo`: Before creating (=`POST`ing) an object of `Foo`, I can create and show a preview to the user and/or save it as a template.
While doing so, the backend (in case of the preview: temporarily) adds the object to the database and returns the full model - including an `ID` in its HTTP response - back to Backbone.
Template- and Preview-objects of `Foo` are (temporarily) saved into the same table, as final objects (column `type` indicates its type (`0` = final/live, `1` = preview, `2` = template)).
When now - after previewing / saving as template - trying to actually CREATE an object of `Foo`, the Backbone model already has the `ID` field set and actually `PUT`s and *updates* the template or not-anymore-existing preview, instead of `POST`ing and therewith *creating* a new `Foo` inside the database (as intended).

**=> solution #1**: calling POST /json/preview does not return the `ID` field, so Backbone doesn't get confused.

**=> solution #2**: overriding parse() of Foo in Backbone-model to kick out ID field from response

***.=> kinda works***

**Example #2**: Having a `Periodic` model, which refers to a `Foo`-template. Intention of a `Periodic` is to offer the user the possibility of semi-automatically creating a new `Foo` object based on a `Foo`-template every X months.

Now there is a call GET /json/periodics, which returns all `Periodic`-objects with its nested `Foo`-objects (`Foo`-templates), including their IDs, e.g. `[{'interval': 12, template_id: 42, template: { 'id': 42, field_1: 'foo', field_2: 'bar', .. } , { .. } , .. ]`.

On the frontend the user now can periodically confirm (or skip) creating a new `Foo`-object, by issuing: `periodics[X].template.save()` which however again `PUT`s and therewith updates the `Foo`-model, instead of `POST`ing and creating a new one (as intended).

Here again (as in example 1), I could strip out the `ID` field of `Foo` - either in the backend or frontend.

However there are situations, where I **need** the `id`-field of templates, e.g. when actually editing them, so here I'd need two calls (`GET /json/templates_WITHOUT_FOO-IDs` and `GET /json/templates_WITH_FOO-IDs`). which also sounds far from right.

**Question is**: What's the right (and consistent) way of avoiding Backbone falsely assuming a model should be `PUT` instead of `POST`ed in certain situations / views?

Comment: You can override `Backbone.sync` and do whatever you want according to your application logic.

Answer (score 0):

> Backbone's save and fetch methods just make calls to the Backbone.sync
>   method, which in turn is just a wrapper for an ajax call. you can pass
>   in ajax parameters using the save function without having to actually
>   extend it. basically ends up being something like this:

```
model.save({attributes you want to save}, {type:'POST', url: 'apiurl/model/:id/played'});
```

You would have to do this every time though so it is probably better practice to extend Backbone.sync for your model.

The Backbone website has a bit of information about what I'm talking about as far as the Backbone sync and save taking ajax options. There are also a few examples I've seen on extending sync but I can't seem to track them down at the moment.